# Whats a N (+,N,-) terminal on battery connection to UPS?

Tags: batteries, ups, instrumentation, electrical

We have a 3 phase ABB powerline series in our site, and we are installing it. In connecting external batteries to the UPS, 4 terminals are given +,N,- and PE. I understand +,- and PE, but for what  "N" stands for? is it neutral? how can we have a neutral in DC battery connection? Please clarify, thanks.

Comment: I think you should submit your inquiry to ABB website. "http://new.abb.com/ups/systems/industrial-ups/powerline-dpa"

Comment: "N" is most likely a neutral terminal for a "Y" configuration 3-phase input or a single phase control supply.  Check the installation manual to be sure.  The qualified installation electrician should have a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The neutral is a reference to the Boost, half of the battery bank serves one cycle and the other half to the other cycle to form the sine wave in the inverter.

Answer (score 1):

Neutral point can be taken from the middle of the battery.
[image]